# Creating a new folder in a bundle

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsbundle

I am creating a new bundle in my application by this way:

File Menu => New => New File... => Resources = Settings bundle...
This is the folder structure I am getting:

- **Test.bundle**
- *Root.plist*
- *en.lproj*

Now I wanted to put an "Images" folder inside it directly under Test.bundle but I am unable to do so. Though I can put Images folder inside "en.lproj" folder, is it good to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bundle is a special folder that Finder displays as a file. You can ask Finder to treat it as a folder by right clicking (or control clicking) on it and choosing `Show Package Contents`. Finder will open a new window inside the bundle, and you can add folders and files as much as you wish.

Comment: +1 I've been wondering this myself for a while. So obvious now! \*facepalm\*